# Moodle reissue a certificate

Tags: php, sql, moodle

I move the data from the certificates_issues table into an archive table, so I am able to reissue the certificate, after a user has done the course again. Now I want to deploy the shifted certificates as a PDF from the archive table. However, this does not work from the archives table. When I write the data back into the original table, it works without problems.

Is there a hint in the Certificate Plug-in that defines the table from which the information must come from? Or how can I move certificates and still provide the function from the certificate plug-in to print it as a PDF? I need all the issued certificates for audits.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving certificates, and printing archived certificates, was added to Totara 2.5 (a distribution of Moodle)

If you are using Moodle 2.5 then you could try merging the certificate code from the MoodleHQ github:

https://github.com/moodlehq/totara/tree/t2-release-2.5/mod/certificate

Or if you are using Moodle 2.6 then the certificate code from the Totara Seedlings github:

https://github.com/totara/seedlings/tree/totara-seedlings-2.6/mod/certificate

Comment: Thanks, but we're using Moodle 2.3.